# How to add transaction deadline?

Tags: web3js, 0x, sendtransaction, binance-smart-chain

I am using web3 to make transactions but I am stuck on how can I add transaction deadlines in
`web3.eth.sendTransaction` function.
I am using 0x API for getting the swap quote.

My code :-

```
await web3.eth.sendTransaction(rawTransaction)
  .then((data: any) => {
     console.log(data)
   })
  .catch(() => {
     alert('error')
  })
```

Comment: what do you mean with deadlines?

Comment: @MajdTL if tranx will not complete in x minutes than it should be canceled automatically

Comment: that is a feature of 0x protocol, right? if yes then it has nothing to do with the  "sendTransaction" method and this deadline infromation should be included somehow in the data of rawTranasction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no transaction deadline on a transaction, you can create Limit Orders with an expiration for this.